# Ajax post value is return empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need some help with my code as I have got a problem with post the value using ajax. When I select the value and click on a button, it will post the empty value when I have defined the variable `$email` and when I tried to use `$_POST['emails']`. I have added `<form action="" method="post">` in my code but it have make no difference so there is something wrong with my button code or somewhere in ajax.

I have tried this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['emails'];
}

<button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;" data-auto-id="<?php echo $autoid; ?>" data-send-email ="<?php echo $email; ?>">Send Test</button>
```

And this:

```
<button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;" data-auto-id="<?php echo $autoid; ?>" data-send-email ="<?php echo $_POST['emails']; ?>">Send Test</button>
```

When I tried to use `$_POST['emails'];` and `echo $email;` as the value are still showing empty.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mydbusername', 'mydbpassword', 'mydbname');
    $param_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $auto_campaign = $_SESSION["auto_campaign"];
    $auto_sql = "SELECT id, subject, day_cycle, enabled, delaysend FROM auto WHERE campaign ='$auto_campaign' AND username ='$param_username'";
    $autoid = '';
    $email = '';

    $results = mysqli_query($link, $auto_sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) 
    { 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            $autoid = $row["id"];
            $autosubject = $row["subject"];
            $autodaycycle = $row["day_cycle"];
            $autoenabled = $row["enabled"];
            $autodelay = $row["delaysend"];
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $email = $_POST['emails'];

    }





?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<style type="text/css">


.calendar-content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 112px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1px;
}


</style>

<div class="calendar-content">
  <div style="margin-left: 40px;margin-top: 20px; height: 40px;">
    <span id="autosubject" style="font-size: 25px;color: #0c7ac0;float: left;">Subject: <?php echo $autosubject ?> </span><br>
    <div style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 15px; height: 40px;">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #ccd5d9; float: left; margin-top: -1px"><a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="#contactModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Send a test</a> | <a name="deleteid" id="deleteid" href="/delete_id.php?id=<?php echo $autoid; ?>"> Delete </a> | Copy to Draft | Settings</span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <!-- email Modal -->
  <div id="contactModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-top: 12%;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="height: 250px;">
        <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Send A Test Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height: 65%;">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label class="label-control" value="">Send test message to email address:</label>
            <select name="emails" id="emails" value="" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 18px; margin-left: 60px;">
              <option selected="selected" value='myemail@gmail.com'>myemail@gmail.com</option>";
            </select><br>
            <button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;" data-auto-id="<?php echo $autoid; ?>" data-send-email ="<?php echo $email; ?>">Send Test</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('#send_email').click(function(e) {
    $(this)
      .html("<span><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending...</span>")
      .prop("disabled", true);
    var ID = $(this).data('auto-id');
    var EMAILS = $(this).data('send-email');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "sendtest.php",
      data: {ID : ID , EMAILS : EMAILS },

      success: function(resultData) {
        alert(resultData);
        $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
        $("#send_email")
          .html("Send Test")
          .prop("disabled", false);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sendtest.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;

}
else if(isset($_POST))
{
    $param_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $param_campaign = $_SESSION['auto_campaign'];
    $id = $_POST['ID'];
    $email = $_POST['EMAILS'];
    echo "your email address is";
    echo $email;
} 
?>
```

Can you please show me an example how I could use the correct way to get the value to post it using ajax after when I click on a button?

Thank you.

Comment: is this all in one big file?  Typically you will want to separate the AJAX backend script from the front end code (for various reasons).  AJAX is more about understanding the Client > Server relationship and how requests happen (work).  Without a good grasp of that... well it will be difficult.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` this will never be set when calling by AJAX only what you send in `data` will be set.  In this case ` data: {ID : ID , EMAILS : EMAILS },`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Right and in one of their other questions, I mentioned they check for errors by enabling error reporting; they still haven't done that, by my not seeing any error handling at all. Either via PHP or the mysql. Which I might add, they should have used a prepared statement and avoid an SQL injection, and have been at this for a while. Making the transition will only cost them more time.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I have removed it but it still dont send the value. Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most glaring thing I see (assuming you have the response/request part covered) is this line in you code that handles the AJAX request

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Because you are sending only `{ID : ID , EMAILS : EMAILS }`  "ID" and "EMAILS" so "submit" will never be set and the code that assigns `$email` will never execute.

**UPDATE1**

This also jumps out:

```
  $email = $_POST['emails'];
```

Now if you recall, this is what we sent `{ID : ID , EMAILS : EMAILS }` so the key `EMAILS` is not the same as `emails` array key checks are case sensitive.  this should be

```
 //in PHP7+
 $email = $_POST['EMAILS'] ?? false;

 //in PHP < 7
 $email = isset($_POST['EMAILS']) ? $_POST['EMAILS'] : false;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have removed it but when I select the value and click on a button, it still show the empty value when I post it using ajax. Any idea?????????